# Unquantifiable integral?

Tags: integration, pi

$$ \pi = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{2-x^2} dx $$

So, thinking I was going to discover something amazing I reasoned that this is equal to pi, and that all I had to do to get the exact value of pi was to find the indefinite integral.

$$ \int \sqrt{2-x^2} dx = \space ? $$

Of course, I couldn't, not even with partial integrals.

So now I'm wondering whether this is possible, but I don't think so.

:)

Comment: Integrands of the form $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ can be integrated using a standard trigonometric substitution of the form $x = a \sin \theta$, $dx = a \cos \theta \, d\theta$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-sqrt%282%29+to+sqrt%282%29+of+sqrt%282-+x%5E2%29

Comment: Your integral is the area of a semi-circle of radius $ \sqrt2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), with $x = \sqrt 2 \sin\theta$.

Then $\,dx = \sqrt 2 \cos\theta\,d\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to trigonometric substitution, you can also argue that this integral is equal to $\pi$ geometrically. As you probably are aware, the definite integral of a non-negative function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is the area of the region bounded by the curves $y = f(x)$, $y = 0$, $x = a$, and $x = b$. For $f(x) = \sqrt{2 - x^2}$, the curve $y = f(x)$ with $-\sqrt 2 \leq x \leq \sqrt 2$ is the semicircle $\{(x,y) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 2 \,\&\, y \geq 0 \}$. So your integral equals half the area within the whole circle $x^2 + y^2 = 2$, which is simply $\frac{1}{2}(2\pi) = \pi$.